# Large POST requests with JSON data are not deserialized in ASP.NET Core 4.6.1

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, json.net, .net-4.6.1

I have a web api:

```
[Route("api/MyResource")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] MyDTO myResource, int resourceId)
```

where MyDTO contains a lot of array of other DTO.

When I send smaller request, everything is ok, but where there are thousands of objects (cca 5 MB) inside MyDTO's arrays, myResource is null.

I've also tried to change the type of myResource parameter to `object`, but I got the same result. Smaller request was deserialized into `JObject`, large into null. I got no exception in the output window or error http response.

I'm debugging the application in IIS-Express.

Why am I getting null and how to fix it?

Comment: It seems like you have a limit on max allowed request size, try to look in web.config if it exists.

Comment: Can you check the exception items in the `ModelState` object and see if there are any exceptions? If so what are they?

Comment: Liero, did you try setting maxAllowedContentLength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `maxAllowedContentLength` in web.config

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

If not success also set

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536" />
</system.web>
```